# MySQL equivalent of php's strtotime()

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, strtotime

Is there a way to convert a string such as "-1 week" or "-5 minutes" into a datetime value in MySQL similar to php's extremely convenient strtotime() function?

I have a table that stores a human-readable time interval (such as "2 minutes") in one column and a `datetime` in another column.

I would like to select the rows where more than the amount of time specified in `interval` has elapsed since `datetime`.

Comment: If it's not in here, it doesn't exist in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have an equivalent of PHP's `strtotime()` in the sense that there is nothing that will automatically attempt to parse and determine the format of a date string using by assuming multiple formats.

What it does have is [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which requires you specify the format of your date, time or date + time string. It is the equivalent of PHP's [`date_create_from_format(format, str)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function (though the format of the format parameter are different).

Here are some examples given from the MySQL documentation. They show a date being passed along with the format string that lets it know how the date string is to be interpreted:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');

SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
```

Alternatively, you can [cast a string to a date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), time or datetime type, but they require a specific format (`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.fraction`) for it to work:

```sql
SELECT CAST("2019-11-21" AS DATE);
```

If you deviate too far from that format it will make a few assumptions but could produce an incorrect date.